# Catch the onClick event on `span` tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have got a lot of span tags inside my div elements. Each div has a unique id.I want to add an onclick event to the span elements in each div uniquley. How can i do that?

```
  <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"id="1">
  <span class="tag label label-info">Access control lists</span> 
  <span class="tag label label-info">Network firewall</span> 
  </div>


  <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"id="2">
  <span class="tag label label-info">Access control lists</span> 
  <span class="tag label label-info">Network firewall</span> 
  </div>
```

My current script which catches all the span elements irrespective of the div.

```
      $('span.label-info').click(function() {

         var news=$('input[type=text][id="vuln<?php echo $model->v_id;?>"]').val()+','+$(this).text();
         $('input[type=text][id="vuln<?php echo $model->v_id;?>"]').val(news);
        return false;
});
```

How can i catch click on span elements inside each div separately?

Comment: `$('#1 span').click(.., $('#2 span').click(..` etc. But why would you want to do this?

Comment: The thing is that i hav got so many tags which is in a table and i want to update only the corresponding <td> based on the tag click.And each row in the table correspond to an object.So the id is object's id.

Comment: And i am using for loop to create my table rows.

Comment: So just use one click handler for all spans, then get its parent td element `$('span.label-info').click(function() { var cell = $(this).closest('td');....`

Comment: Since you are creating the table dynamically, it should be `$('#mytable').on('click', 'span.label-info', function() {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at it the wrong way. Instead of having a separate click handler for each div, you can keep the shared click handler, but find out which div is the parent, and use its ID in the subsequent selectors.

```
$('span.label-info').click(function() {

    // find the parent/ansector that is a div and has the class
    var divId = $(this).closest('div.bootstrap-tagsinput').prop('id');

    var news=$('input[type=text][id="vuln' + divId + '"]').val()+','+$(this).text();
    $('input[type=text][id="vuln' + divId + '"]').val(news);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work to add a click even handler to each span.

```
$('span.label-info').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('id'); //<--$(this) is a handle to the clicked span
    $(this).parent().attr('id'); //<-- $(this).parent() references the parent div
});
```

It's worth mentioning, consider changing `.click()` to `.on('click')`.

Also - if you wanted to bind once without rebinding after spans were dynamically added to the div, you could bind it like this:

```
$('div').on('click', 'span.label-info').click(function() {  
   /* <-- do stuff with $(this) or $(this).parent() here --> */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/GZVdL/3/

Hi.

in your span click event you can find parent div and then get its attribute id to find which div it is.
Below is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".tag").click(function(){


    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks. But how will i take that span value to update a div in between those two divs(which is not the parent div)?

Comment: you can give custom tag to span divID which you eant to update check the fiddle i have change it accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/GZVdL/5/